# How do I create an OLE Control?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, ole

Without going into [why I need OLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137586/how-do-i-embed-a-custom-user-control-in-ms-word).. I need to embed a managed C++ custom control into MS Word 2007 (2003 also would be nice).

### So the question is How do I make this managed (.net 3.5) control OLE compliant ?

It seems that I need to do something akin to implementing an interface. But an up-to-date tutorial is something that is proving difficult to find.

I've read the wikipedia article on OLE. All the information that I could google out is ancient (1994) and/or VB centric (4.0-6.0). Anything that makes sense to current times... links/books please post.

Thanks for reading..

Comment: I also would like to see an answer to this..

Comment: OLE _is_ ancient. You're not going to get _too_ much better than "Inside OLE2"

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Whitechapel writes about managed controls as ActiveX controls in Office documents. You can read his article here: http://blogs.msdn.com/andreww/archive/2008/11/24/using-managed-controls-as-activex-controls.aspx.

Update: See also this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023004/embedding-objects-into-microsoft-word-and-openoffice-writer/2023212#2023212).

Comment: But he says 'it doesnt work that well with word.' Also 'dont try this in production code'. Both needed by me :) Thanks anyways